Why didn't Smith give Atlas painkillers during the surgery?
In Atlas (2024), Atlas (portrayed by Jennifer Lopez) has leg surgery performed by an AI mech robot named Smith.
Why didn't Smith give Atlas any painkillers during the procedure?

I've not seen the film. Isn't it post-apocalyptic? Are there even painkillers available?

@Valorum I haven't seen it either, but from the bits I've heard much of the movie takes place essentially in a battlefield, so I'm guessing the question is probably about battlefield medicine.  Not an answer, since I don't know for certain.

@Valorum post apoc, sort of, but by this time its on another planet. Painkillers are available, and it was up to an AI to administer it, presumably, but it jokes (i think) instead.

@DavidW well, medicine administered by a super AI inside the mech that Lopez is in. It just seems to be a joke.

potentially its the AI having a joke:
(background: ai is trying to learn from her to better engage with her, noticing shes quite bitter and sarcastic most of the time)
partway into the leg surgery, atlas groans some more, and the Ai goes 'Oops, missed a step", and then sprays something presumably pain-suppressing on her:




afterwards she gets a lollypop
awesome movie!
note, this review mentions it:
https://nerdist.com/article/atlas-movie-starring-jennifer-lopez-review/

That supercomputer also forgets a “step” during a clearly defined, easy procedure. It’s not funny in anyway, despite trying to be. It’s just needlessly stupid.


That review does seem to have missed the obvious fact that it was a joke on the part of the character in-universe. It is not necessary that the audience find it funny (although I did).

I suppose it reflects the unevenness of the movie. However, by this time the characters 'personality' is established.. The briefing scene had me laughing, but only because it appeared to be a parody of Aliens... It is possible to be missed though, when English is not the first language or the culture that is viewing this is not used to that kind of humor...
